# How to use layout.jade in express 3.0.0rc2

Tags: node.js, layout, express, pug

I just updated to express 3.0.0rc2 . Everything works fine except the layout.jade isn't used anymore. When I had the old version I just was using this line to set jade as default view engine.

```
app.set("view engine", "jade");
```

I'm rendering like this right now but it doesn't work.

```
app.render(view, {opt1: 1,opt2: 2, layout: "layout.jade"}, callback);
```

I didn't needed this before but just in case I tried this out with no success

```
app.set("view options", {
    layout: true
});
```

I even tried it like this:

```
app.engine('jade', require('jade').__express);
// instead of this: app.set("view engine", "jade");
```

I hope someone knows how to use the layout.jade in the new version. Thanks